# Use 64-bit library from 32-bit application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, 32bit-64bit

My .NET application is 32-bit because I use TWAIN inside it. But I need to write 64-bit library or app and call its methods from my program. 
I must create a 64-bit library to interact with WMI SMO, and its functions don't work properly if it compiled as 32-bit dll.

How can I resolve this issue? Is it possible to use a 64-bit library from a 32-bit application?

Comment: A process is *either* 32-bit or 64-bit. Which is determined early on and by the EXE's settings. If you need both 32-bit and 64-bit code then you need two *separate* processes and then to use some form of IPC between them

Comment: I personally use [Protocol Buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) for the IPC communication.  I makes serializing data very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference a 32-bit library from a 64-bit executable and viceversa. This is a technical limitation.

However, depending on your other constraints, you may decide to employ a service-based architecture to avoid issues like yours and be more agile in the future.

In fact, you could write "micro" services specialized to solve one single purpose (*scanning*, *interacting with WMI*, etc...) and then call them from your application.
This way, you are completely free to choose whichever technology/architecture you require to achieve every single task your application requires. Isolating your "features" in services, allows you to have a different evolutionary path per service, as each service is loosely coupled with each others.

This solution requires writing more code than using a library. First you need to create a windows service ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications)) to
wrap your code, then you need to implement the communication channel. Have a look at [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial) and [WebApi2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to have an idea of what you can achieve.